# Property Details Broken Down in IDX Broker plugin

Tags: wordpress, idx, idxbroker

I have Platinum account of IDX Broker, I am using IMPress Listings plugin to get listing in my site , but the issue is that not all fields are displayed in the plugin many remain blank.

I can only get primary details , I am unable to get Extended Details. Is there paid plugin that i need to purchase for this?

Answer (score 2):

You are not required to have any paid plugins when using IMPress Listings. The IDX Broker import feature (requires a paid IDX Broker account) for IMPress Listings will only import data for which the IDX Broker API returns, which is not all the fields that get displayed on the IDX Broker detail pages. All we can do about this is request IDX Broker to update the API to return all fields.

If the issue is they are in WordPress but not displaying on the front of your site, it might be a conflict issue with your theme. If this is the case you can copy the template file to your theme and modify the design and what gets displayed.

Further Reading:

- IDX Broker API - Featured Properties

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You need to go Pages --> Advanced search --> fields.. You can add advanced fields in idx broker of your choice. I don't think any conflict can stop advance field display.